# Unable to display image in JSP page

Tags: java, image, rest, jsp

Hi i am getting path of the image in REST API call as below

```
<hotel-info:thumb-nail-image>/4014/40140/images/Result_tn.jpg</hotel-info:thumb-nail-image>
```

How to display image in JSP page ?

In JAXB class :

```
@XmlElement(name = "thumb-nail-image", required = true)
protected String thumbNailImage;
```

In JSP :

```
<img src="data:image/jpg;base64,${hotelFareResult.basicInfo.thumbNailImage}" alt="Could Not Load Img" width="200" height="200">
```

Please help me how to display image in JSP ?

Comment: Forget about Java, JSPs, REST, etc. for a moment. Concentrate on pure HTML How do you display an image located at `/4014/40140/images/Result_tn.jpg` in HTML?

Comment: I would suggest you to go through via network tab and confirm your images are there or not. If yes, go through the path and confirm.

Answer (score 0):

[STS project explorer drop downs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QdFNP.png)

Firt of all i am using spring tool suite and i now find solution for displaying image in jsp page.
first you need to have a name.xml file in /webapp/WEB-INF/views/name.xml
xml file must be in views folder in WEB-INF and include the content below........

```
<bean xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-4.0.xsd
<mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**"
        location="/resources/" /></bean>
```

........
then place the images folder in the webapp inside the resource folder so that you have access it easily.
if you done it properly then add path to place you want like this

```
<img src="/resources/images/name.png"
                        height="40px" width="55px">
```

if you have any doubt ...tell me comment